# How can I get Unlocker to show in the Windows right-click context menu?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit

I have installed the 64 bit version for my 64 bit windows 10 PC. 
I am trying to get this:

[image]

Comment: Install unlocker from here? http://www.majorgeeks.com/mg/getmirror/unlocker,1.html, make sure to click advanced so you don't get the adware

Comment: Oh your file is a bit different although the same version . It worked though , thanks a bunch! My file had had .msi as the file extension.

Answer (score 5):

I found out Unlocker is no longer working in the context menu anymore on Windows 10.

I tried [IObit Unlocker](https://www.iobit.com/en/iobit-unlocker.php) and it worked. Try it.

Comment: Unlocker in context menu works with the link provided by@mt025. The difference I found is mine is a .msi file whereas his is an .exe file

Answer (score 2):

You need to set this as an option when you install unlocker. If you haven't got it installed you can download from here:

[MajorGeeks Unlocker Mirror](http://majorgeeks.com/mg/getmirror/unlocker,1.html)

Make sure to click advanced when installing so you don't get the adware.

Comment: I do not see such option, when installing Unlocker 1.9.2. From MajorGeeks there is IObitUnlocker_3135437965.exe under download link for Unlocker which is failing during installation with "Product configuration is missing!" message for me...

Comment: @mt025, the author of unlocker advice people to download the portable version of unlocker [https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/unlocker_portable.html]. And be careful the version you mention is buggy on Windows 10.